# SQL - Change Tracking Version with Retention Period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

What happens to Change Tracking Version(SYS_Change_Version) after the retention period.

Column - SYS_Change_Version 
Do they start over all again?

For instance: Initial numbers 1,2,3 after retention period does it start 
from 1,2,3 again or do it from 4,5,6..

Please advise.